# Is "ab octo vocibus" a correct translation of "for eight voices"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, music

I'm wondering because of a composition I'm writing. I'm thinking of "Contrapunctus duplex ab octo vocibus" as a title for a movement.

Comment: Welcome to the site! The answer will depend on context. Can you give a whole sentence where you intend to use the phrase? You can always edit your question to add details.

Comment: "Contrapunctus duplex ab octo vocibus", as a title for a movement.

Comment: Thanks! I edited your question with the details. Feel free to edit further yourself. (For the record, even after your comment I had no clue that this had to do with music. I had to see the answers. Always better to explain a little too much!)

Comment: Thanks for adding the music tag, if that was you.

Answer (score 8):

No: if I have interpreted it correctly, "for eight voices" indicates the instrument by which the action takes place, which in this case are the voices of those who have to sing: the sentence must therefore be translated with per + accusative: “*Contrapunctus duplex **per octo voces***”.

Moreover, it is a frequent formulation in musical composition: for an *exempli gratia* comparison, you can think of Sven-David Sandstrom's "*Kyrie et Agnus Dei **per tres voces***" or of Johann Vinnubst's "*Missa Dominicalis **per tres voces** cum organo*".

EDIT: as it was shown in the comments and in the other answer, this kind of  phrases have been translated in different ways over the years. However, the instrumental ablative could be fine if it is intended that the "*voces*" are musical instruments.

We have seen that also *a / ab* + ablative is very widespread in the traditional wording: this is because it presupposes a gerundive with a *verbum cantandi* (e.g. "*Contrapunctus duplex ab octo vocibus **canendus***"); however the dative of agent could also work well ("*Contrapunctus duplex octo vocibus **canendus***").

Comment: Still, Google finds expressions like "ab una et duabus vocibus," "Canon a tribus vocibus," "Vespera a quattuor vocibus" etc. (perhaps *sc. cantus, -a, -um*).

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel A solo keyboard player can perform contrapuntal music. J S Bach (and others) routinely wrote "a 3" etc to indicate this. But note that in orchestral scores, markings like "a 2" or "a 3" have the *opposite* meaning - i.e. that several instrumentalists should play the *same* monophonic part in unison.

Comment: Yes, it implies a gerundive. A very neat analysis. We actually all agree about something.

Comment: @qwertxyz The per + accusative translation makes a lot of sense. You say that the instrumental ablative could be fine if the "voces" are musical instruments: I am using "voces" to mean "independent melodic lines", as a translation of the term "voice" as used in the study of counterpoint. These voices just so happen to also be for eight instruments, but that is not what I mean, nor am I referring to voices, as in singing. That being said, what I'm hearing from both answers is that either (the instrumental ablative and the per + accusative) is fine and that they both have precedent.

Answer (score 6):

I am following up on Sebastian's comment. J.S. Bach gave Latin titles to many of his compositions, among them a “Canon triplex a 6 voc(ibus)”, and many others with the same construction. One could argue that this is a macaronic mixture of Latin with Italian or French. But one could also argue that it is wide-spread and standardised usage among composers of polyphonic music (which was, of course, unknown to the ancient Romans). I think if it was good enough for Bach it should be good enough for us, mere mortals that we are.

AN AFTERTHOUGHT: I have looked at this some more. The autograph superscription to the second part of the Matthew Passion reads: Pars 2da Passionis Christi secundum Matthaeum a due Chori per J.S. Bach. The first six words are Latin. “A due Chori” is not Latin, but unmistakably Italian, apart from the Latinising “h” (NB: Italian “a” is from ad, not ab). “Per”, to indicate the name of the author/composer, is neither Latin nor Italian; it seems rather to be a calque on French “par”.

Comment: *Sanctissimae Virgini Missa senis vocibus ac Vesperae pluribus decantandae* by Verdi is an example that seems to use a dative. More recently, I see *Cantiones Sacrae Quinis Vocibus* and *Moduli Quinis Vocibus*. Not that I have a problem with *per voces*, but the dative seems well attested.